# spring addResourceHandler for text files

Tags: spring

Why `addResourceHandler("/*.text")` not work while `addResourceHandler("/*.js")` works fine?
If spring doesn't support text file resource handler,how can we make it in other ways?

```
    @Override
public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
//not work,localhost:8181/test.text  get "HTTP Status 404  The requested resource is not available."
    if (!registry.hasMappingForPattern("/*.text")) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/*.text").addResourceLocations("/static/text/");
    }
//works fine,localhost:8181/test.js get the right file
    if (!registry.hasMappingForPattern("/*.js")) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/*.js").addResourceLocations("/static/js/");
    }

}
```

Comment: how do you access these text resources?

Comment: Please be specific what do you mean by "not works". Do you get an error?

Comment: @HarshilSharma Yes,HTTP Status 404,The requested resource is not available.

Comment: @kuhajeyan just use localhost:8181/test.text in url pattern

Comment: @XYzAmos the URL "localhost:8181/test.text" suggests that you are deploying your app in ROOT context. Is that true? Also, whats tthe URL you use for js files? And please include any tomcat/app log snippets relevant.

Comment: @HarshilSharma See the updated question.The js file use the same url pattern `localhost:8181/test.js`.(In IDEA, u can skip your project name.) I do assume that spring does not handle TEXT file    resquests in `/*.text` pattern while js,css,imgs works fine.